# How to see the scripts used by a page in chrome inspector

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I use chrome and have used developer tools inspector in Chrome many times in the past to see which scripts a page is using, but in the latest version of Chrome, there is no 'Resources' tab in the inspector.  How do I see which scripts are enqueued on a given page via inspector now?

Comment: How does this relate to WP? Sounds like you have an issue with Chrome, right?

Comment: Use a plugin like query monitor

Comment: hmm, you arent wrong.  I need to see the scripts loaded on a page of my wp website, but now that you bring this up I guess it is more of a chrome question... answer if you know but if not, I'll go ask at the appropriate place

Comment: thanks @Benoti .  I have never used query monitor.  Will it show the javascript and JQuery scripts loaded on each page?

Comment: It displays everything for the page loaded in front or admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you check loaded scripts in source code? All the scripts will be listed there, unless you minified them.

Comment: ok, that worked well, but what I am looking for is the new 'Resources' tab in the google chrome Inspector.  Where is that functionality now?  It seems to be in 'Sources' but I don't see my custom enqueed scripts anywhere even though they are definitely loaded (as I could see with your solution of just viewing source)

Comment: It is there, just choose your domain and you find there all the scripts loaded to current page, sorted by folder.